# Checking whether current date is within a days limit field date MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, intervals, unix-timestamp

In my project I need the user subscribed plans which are not expired. When a user subscribe to a plan, it will be entered in a table *usersubscription* with structure as shown below:

```
id  user_id   plan_id  subscribed_on
```

The table for storing plan details is *subscription_plans*:

```
id  plan   days_limit  discounted_rate  added_on    status  rate
1   PlanJ  30          240              1403094260  1       245.00
```

This table will contain details of subscription plans in the project. A video can be part of one or more plans. If a video is under a plan it will be stored in database *subscribed_videos*.

```
id   plan_id  videoid
```

Also a plan can be part of another plan. That is suppose there are plans say A and B. Video 1 is part of plan B and plan a contains plan B also (associated plans). So if the user subscribe to plan A, the videos in plan B will be available for him. The table for associated plans is *subscription_groups*. The structure is shared below:

```
id  plan_id  assosiated_plan_id  added_on
```

What I need is to check whether user has subscribed to a plan (containing selected video) which is not expired (ie,it will expire on *subscribed_on+days_limit* day). The current query which I am using now is

```
    select u.id,sp.days_limit from usersubscription as u INNER JOIN subscription_plans as 
sp ON sp.id=u.plan_id where (plan_id IN ( ( SELECT DISTINCT plan_id FROM subscribed_videos
 sv where sv.videoid = 57 ) ) OR id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT assosiated_plan_id AS plan_id FROM
subscription_groups sg JOIN subscribed_videos sv ON sv.plan_id = sg.plan_id WHERE 
sv.videoid = 57 ) ) and u.user_id=1 AND DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.subscribed_on), INTERVAL 
sp.days_limit DAY) > NOW()
```

This will check whether a user with id 1 is subscribed to any plans (main plan or associated plan) containing video with id 57. I am saving date as integer (unix timestamp).

Can anyone help me to find a solution to this? Please check this [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44001/1)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Error is solved . [Check here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44001/18)

Just point the id after the OR clause in subquery to what ever field you want